# Including day of week in a logit model

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data

Let's say that I am putting together a logistic regression model where I am predicting 
something (y) based on the day of the week. However, the model needs to account for each single day.

Therefore, instead of:

```
y = B0 + B1*(day)
```

Where day is a categorical variable with 7 levels.

It would be:

```
y = B0 + B1*(monday) + B2*(tuesday) + B3*(wednesday) + ... + B7*(sunday)
```

I'm basically thinking that each day needs a separate coefficient because each 
has a different affect on y. However, I think each will need to be a dummy variable 
so that for monday, 1 is for monday, and 0 for not monday, and so forth.

I'm just curious if there is a statistical logic to doing it the second way 
with separate days? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Almost. You can't have a dummy for every day of the week plus an intercept term because that generates multicolinearity. The easiest thing is to just include 6 day of the week dummies, with the intercept acting like the dummy for the seventh day. This formulation is (generally) much preferred to your first suggestion.

Comment: Just remember to choose which day you want to compare the other days too, otherwise the software will select the lowest category, and that may not be the contrast you want. To convert Day, just do `as.factor(Day)`

Comment: @Michelle The choice of the baseline category depends on the statistical package; R uses the lowest level in lexicographic order, while SAS if I remember correctly uses the latest.

Comment: @chl good points as per normal. :) Take home message: make sure the baseline category that the software chooses is the one you want used, check how your software picks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The model with day as a categorical variable with seven levels does account for each single day; you don't need to do it "by hand", so to speak.

For example:

```
library(MASS)

# Construct sample data: 700 observations, 100 on each of 7 days of week
Day <- factor(rep(c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"), 100),
              levels=c("Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"),
              ordered=TRUE)
Day.effect <- rep(rnorm(7), 100)
y <- rbinom(700, 1, 1/(1+exp(-Day.effect)))

# Estimate logit model without intercept (captures each day's effect)
foo <- summary(glm(y~Day-1, family=binomial))

# compare actuals to estimates
coefs <- foo$coefficients
coefs <- cbind(Day.effect, coefs)
colnames(coefs)[1] <- "Actual"
options(digits=3)

> coefs
             Actual Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
DayMonday     0.520    0.490      0.206   2.376 1.75e-02
DayTuesday   -0.230   -0.323      0.203  -1.593 1.11e-01
DayWednesday -0.247   -0.447      0.205  -2.182 2.91e-02
DayThursday  -1.156   -1.266      0.241  -5.243 1.58e-07
DayFriday     0.282    0.160      0.201   0.799 4.24e-01
DaySaturday  -0.383   -0.405      0.204  -1.986 4.70e-02
DaySunday    -0.357   -0.447      0.205  -2.182 2.91e-02
```

This would appear to do just what you want.